# query to connect to another instance of Another SQL sever not using linked server or SQLCMD mode

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i dont want to use SQLCMD mode or addlinkedserver...i m creating a sp which will fire from central server and collect the data from multiple server...i just want query..
query to connect to another instance of Another SQL sever not using linked server or SQLCMD mode so that I can just paste that in the top of the create script and F5 to run it and it would switch to the new server and run the create script.
I dont want to use SP_addLinkedserver i.e. i dont want to link the server....I just want to Connect to that server....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Server Group which allows you to run a script against multiple servers. See [Create a Central Management Server and Server Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126.aspx). The good thing is that the queries are run concurrently, not serially, and the result sets are concatenated by SSMS into a single result set. For interactive queries it works OK. The bad thing is when you have failures the retry and rerun can be tricky.

For automation though using SQLCMD mode or [PowerShell cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245198.aspx) is a far better alternative.